# Android product partition vs. vendor partition

Tags: partitions

What's the difference between `product` partition and `vendor` partition? After flashing a GSI image, `product` partition is missing but `vendor` partition is there. I am confused about where should my application be installed.

In recent releases, more partitions were created in Android: `system`, `vendor`, `product`, `odm`, and `system_ext`. It's hard to understand it from the official document, wish someone can help summarize it here.

Answer (score 2):

The `product` partition is an extension of the `system` partition. OEMs install stock Android system image in the `/system` partition. The customisation they do to the Android framework is stored in the `/product` partition. This allows a single system image across all OEMs' devices and unique customisations in the `product` partition. There's a weak ABI between the `system` and `product` partition which links `product` to the Android framework. GSI works without product partition.

Similarly, vendor image can be generic for multiple devices with the same SoC or the same family of SoC. `vendor` partition contains the Board Support Package (BSPs) of the SoC. Vendor customisations are included in the `/odm` partition and `odm` is linked with `vendor` by a weak ABI. The `vendor` partition still works without `odm`.

[See all the components of ODM](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/odm-partitions#odm-components).

[image]

`product` is an extension of the Android framework and `odm` is an extension of `vendor` modules.