# Android 10: Difference Between System, Product and Vendor Partition

Tags: partitions, android-10, system-apps, sony-xperia, ab-partition

Android has read only A/B partitions where different apps are preloaded by OEM:

```
/system/app
/system/priv-app
/product/app
/product/priv-app
/vendor/app
/vendor/priv-app
```

Questions:

What is privilege/permissions difference between all above file path?
OEMS App, SOC Manufactures Apps and Third Party Apk are preloaded in which partitions?

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Android product partition vs. vendor partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236212/44325)