# System and Vendor Partitions

Tags: partitions, system

If `system` partition of Android contains important binaries and `vendor` partition contains binaries and files related to vendor or manufacturer.

1. Then do all modification made by vendor or manufacturer (like samsung) are contained in vendor partion?
2. And does `system` partition only contain the binaries of stock Android and no modifications from manufacturer? If not they what special does `vendor` partition contain that it is made apart as a different partition?

Comment: "The vendor partition continues to host SoC-specific Board Support Package (BSP) code which can be shared among multiple devices based on the given SoC."  [source](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/partitions/product-partitions#product-partitions) This means the vendor partition is in my understanding only supposed to contain low-level code related to the SoC/CPU/chipset.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Possibly related/dupe: [Android product partition vs. vendor partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236212/44325)